# MySQL prompted twice for password

Tags: php, mysql, database, cmd, wampserver

So I created a user account for a database entitled "publications" with a password...

> e.g. GRANT ALL ON publications.* to 'myname'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypasswd';

As usual, I type

```
C:\....address of mysql.exe..." -u username
```

However, it doesn't work and cmd closes!

I then type

```
C:\....address of mysql.exe..." -u username -p mypassword
```

And it opens, but I am prompted for yet another password.

I try my best to enter my password which I know is correct, and I am continuously locked out of my account.

I just started MySQL/PHP web programming. Please help! Do I have to reinstall my Wamp Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux at least (not tried on Win) there is no space between the `-p` and the password when entered on the command line

```
sudo mysql -u admin -ppassword
```

With the space MySQL will prompt you for the password

Answer (score 1):

Instead of typing your password on the same line as the rest of the command, try and leave it with -p at the end.. Then it should ask for your password on the next line where it should let you in only once.

Comment: Works as well! Thank you A3mercury!